# How to make special manifest entries for intel xdk android plugin

Tags: android, intel-xdk

I want to use java plugin in intel XDK for android project. I am following intel written plugin development tutorial and able to develop and use my plugin very well.

**Problem**: I have develop one more plugin which need some **specific entries in the manifest file**. There is one option/"text box" to enter manifest file in intel XDK which comes while uploading plugin, and the text box is labeled as "Enter Manifest". I have pasted my manifest file in this text box but these manifest entries are not taking effect. My special manifest entry which i want to make is a activity tag. Please let me know, if there is some other way to make these entries.

Comment: Are you referring to creating a plugin for the "old" XDK or a plugin for use with your HTML5 app?

Comment: I am following this url: http://www.html5dev-software.intel.com/documentation/nativeplugins/index.html. I have installed current version of xdk. Please help me out. Do you want to see the screen shot of "how i made custom entries of manifest file"?

Comment: I have posted same question on intel forum as well. https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=5239

Answer (score 1):

That plugin documentation refers to building plugins for the old AppMobi XDK and container. That feature is being phased out and will, eventually, be replaced by standard Cordova 3.x plugins. Unfortunately, the Cordova 3.x plugin support is not yet available, so we're in limbo right now. We will be supporting Cordova plugins in a future release, but company policy prevents us from publishing a release date or roadmap. When such a feature is supported it will be posted on the forum and will be highlighted in the release notes.

For now, I would invest any plugin development time in Cordova plugins using the Cordova CLI. When we support the use of those plugins you'll be able to take that code and reuse it with the XDK.